# Get success on UITest when waitForExpectations fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

I have a task to get UITest successfully passed, if expected element (alert in my case) DIDN'T appear before timeout (on server request).

Code:

```
let element = app.alerts["test text"]
let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
expectation(for: existsPredicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)

waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)

// when timeout expired test should finish with success
```

Didn't find any solutions over Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оооо, you should mind it’s `UITest`. In that case expectation has nice property: `isInverted`. Setting this to true, says that expectation is not intended to happen. )))

```
let element = app.alerts["test text"]
let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
let expectation = expectation(for: existsPredicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
expectation.isInverted = true // if alert doesn't appear during 10 seconds, then test passed

waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
```

Comment: Brilliant! It exactly what I needed! Thank you for this clue! Post code and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I added it myself. Delete previous answer, please.